# simplify double summation f(x)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working with image quality measurements method, and I  simplify the following double summation  :
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^M  \sum_{j=1}^N (f(i,j) - h(i,j))}{\sum_{i=1}^M  \sum_{j=1}^N f(i,j)}=1-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^M  \sum_{j=1}^N h(i,j)}{\sum_{i=1}^M  \sum_{j=1}^N f(i,j)}$$ 
Is this simplify true or not ? if not how can i simplify it.

Comment: Yes, it's valid. Split the two terms of the sun in the numerator; the first is equal to the denominator so it simplifies to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine, assuming that $\sum\sum f \ne 0$.  Since the sums are finite, you don't have to worry about convergence, and so the usual rules of associativity, commutativity, and distributivity apply without difficulty.

To elaborate:
\begin{equation}
\sum \sum (f - h) = \sum \sum f - \sum \sum h
\end{equation}
by the commutative and associative properties of addition.  Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sum\sum (f-h)}{\sum\sum f}
= \frac{\sum\sum f - \sum \sum h}{\sum \sum f}
= \frac{\sum\sum f}{\sum \sum f} - \frac{\sum\sum h}{\sum \sum f}
\end{equation}
by the distributive property of multiplication over addition (where we are multiplying both sums in the numerator by $\left(\sum\sum f\right)^{-1}$, which is just a nonzero real number.  Simplifying gives your result.

Comment: thank  platty and Xander Henderson  for your answers